# how to subtract Duration from LocalTime in Hibernate SQL

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I have a `Duration` field called `mobileAdditionalDuration` in my `AppointmentEntity` entity in Hibernate. In my `AppointmentRepository` interface, I am trying to write a SQL query that subtracts this duration from the `startTime` and `endTime` fields, which are of type `LocalTime`.

Here is the query I have written:

```
    @Query(
        value = """
            SELECT EXISTS (
                SELECT 
                    a.date, 
                    SUBTIME(a.startTime, a.mobileAdditionalDuration) as startTime1, 
                    SUBTIME(a.endTime, a.mobileAdditionalDuration) as endTime1 
                FROM appointment a 
                WHERE (a.date = ?1) AND ((startTime1 < ?2 AND endTime1 > ?2) OR (startTime1 < ?3 AND endTime1 > ?3))
        )
    """
    )
    fun checkIfAppointmentAlreadyExistAtThisTime(date: LocalDate, start: LocalTime, end: LocalTime): Boolean
```

However, when I run the query, I get the exception `Could not interpret path expression 'aStartTime'`. Can someone help me correct my query to achieve the desired result?

Comment: sp you change teh query and do you get another error message?

Comment: @nbk Yes, i get the same error

Comment: i can't see any aStartTime in your code, so the error could not  appear that way, but you still can't use startTime1  or endTime1  in your code , because they don't exist, when the code is parsed, you need to repeat SUBTIME(a.startTime, a.mobileAdditionalDuration)  and SUBTIME(a.endTime, a.mobileAdditionalDuration) in the WHERE clause

Answer (score 0):

The HQL `-` operator is used to subtract a `Duration` from a `LocalTime`, as described here:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-Datetime-arithmetic